# iphone renderInContext not capturing iAd

Tags: iphone, capture, iad

I have managed to add an iAd to a table cell which is working as expected.  When the user taps a table cell I want to perform a specific animation, so I captured the view using the code below into a UIImage then transform the image.  This works perfectly apart form the fact that the captured image contains everything appart from the iAd.  I have swapped iAds for AdMob and it works fine, so must be something to do with the way an iAd is attached to the view tree.  Any one have any ideas on how to capture the iAd image.

```
CGRect rect = view.bounds;  
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);  
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
[view.layer.superlayer renderInContext:context];  
UIImage *imageCaptureRect;    
imageCaptureRect = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
self.capturedImage = imageCaptureRect;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess that this is by design.  Apple uses the personal information they have on their users and their account histories to target iAds to the correct demographics.  If Apple allowed developers to determine which iAds a user was receiving, they would be leaking this personal information.  Consider the possibility that an iAd was targeted to people under the age of 30.  An application that captured your iAds could watch out for this advert and determine your age bracket.